# Файл exe при открытии выдает ошибку. Собрал его с помощью Intellij idea

Tags: java, javafx

ошибка следующая"class Main not found". и затем"Failed to launch JVM"
создовал по комментарию Alexandr-Dolgov оно последнее здесь: http://info.javarush.ru/iruslan/2014/03/20/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-exe-%D0%B2-intellij.html 
     вот скрин, класс Main указал вроде верно, почему он его не может найти
   [image: Настройки artifacts]

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Name");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Вообщем как мне решить данную проблему, или какие есть альтернативы кроме как запускать со среды разработки, ведь там оно работает прекрасно.

Comment: опишите процесс настройки артефакта и деплоя

Comment: я настраивал следующим образом
"В IDEA можно сделать .exe для JavaFX приложения, для этого идем File — Project Structure.
В выпадающем списке выбираем JavaFX Application
В правой части окна переходим на вкладку JavaFX
Заполняем поля. Можно заполнить только Application Class указав там класс с методом main
И самое главное в Native bundle выбираем all
И в верхней части этого окна ставим галочку Build on make
И еще выше задаем Output directory"

Comment: В принципе, на скрине все настройки видны, в других вкладках я ничего не менял.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена, был оказывается не правильно указан класс, с методом main. Я написал Main, а надо было с указанием папки, в которой находится этот класс в моем проекте, т.е. в моем случае sample.Main.

Answer (score 2):

Была та же самая проблема.
class лежал в папке `E:\Artem Java\Banner`
в `Aplication class` указал путь `Banner.Banner`  всё заработало.
1й Banner - название папки.
2й Banner - название класса.

Через указатель пути (троеточее) указать путь не получается, выдаёт ошибку: Banner is not acceptable.
Когда прописал в ручную путь, всё получилось.